# python playwright - issues with typing inside the input fields

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to write the script with python playwright to log in on the website, this is my code:

```
import json
import sys
import bs4
import urllib.parse

link = 'https://secure.libertycable.com/login.php'
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    #browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36')
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto(link)
    try:
        try:
            page.click('#close')
        except Exception as e:
            page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
        page.type('#user input[name="email"]', "xxxxx")
        page.type('#myInput input[name="password"]', "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()      
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script.")
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()
```

This is part of the page source:

```
     <form class="form-group" id="login_form2" name="login_form2" method="post" action="do_login.php">\n                <input type="hidden" name="go_url" value="">\n                <div style="width:50%;">\n                <label>Email Address*:</label><br>\n                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="user" size="25" value="">\n                <label>Password*:</label><br><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="myInput" size="25" value="">\n                    <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password" title="View Password" onclick="passwordToggle()"></span>\n                </div>\n                <br clear="all">\n                <div class="btn btn-green" onclick="document.getElementById(\'login_form2\').submit();"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw"></i> Login</div>\n                <br><span class="text-muted">*Please Note: Email address and password are case sensitive!</span>\n                </form>\n                <br>\n                <p><a href="reset-password.php" class="blueText">Forgot Password?</a></p>\n
```

The script goes to the page, closes the popup window that has id #close, and that works fine, but then when needs to fill the input fields, the script does nothing, any help?

Answer (score 1):

`user` and `myInput` are IDs on the input element itself and not on one of the parent elements. This means, that using a selector like this works in your scenario:

```
    page.type('input[name="email"]#user', "xxxxx")
    page.type('input[name="password"]#myInput', "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

The reason why it hangs is that it can't find the element. I would recommend to follow the [Playwright debugging tools](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug) section to either use `DEBUG=pw:api` or the `PWDEBUG=1` to get debug logs why its hanging - in your case it would tell you that the selector cannot be found.

Comment: Input for email works, but for password still not working